# When dealing with user input getch() from ncurses is better then multithreading?

Tags: multithreading, ncurses

I am developing a game and for now I am using the `getch` function provided by ncurses library.

From [here](https://linux.die.net/man/3/nodelay):

> The `nodelay` option causes `getch` to be a non-blocking call. If no input is ready, getch returns ERR. If disabled (bf is FALSE), getch waits until a key is pressed.

That is, by default `getch()` is a blocking function and if you set `nodelay` to TRUE you can have a non-blocking input user function.

In another approach I can use multithreading to catch user input without blocking the course of the game.

**QUESTION**

Am I wasting time to rewrite my codes using threads or can I gain something (speed response, portability, etc) using that approach?

Ncurses is a nice library to make console applications but I have this doubt about user inputs.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a multithreaded application with more than one thread using the display, it won't work — without some effort.

The ncurses FAQ tells more: *[Why does (fill in the blank) happen when I use two threads?](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#multithread)*